# FullCalendar How can I resize the cell height of my header?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I need to resize the cell height of my fullCalendar header. Currently there is too much white space (padding?) on the top and below of the month. Here is what it currently looks like. [image]

I would like it to display more like this

[image]

Actually the two images look pretty similar. I guess I just don't want any white space above or below the month text. Please help if you can. Thanks

Comment: Here is a jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/OhioGTO1969/dphtuyyu/  in case it can be used for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with this jQuery line after FullCalendar in instantiated::

```
$(".fc-toolbar").css({"margin-bottom":0});
```

Or via a CSS rule (probably the best way):

```
.fc-toolbar{
  margin-bottom:0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Well that works (kind of) it moves the text down to the bottom but still leaves too much white space on top. I tried to also add ".fc-toolbar{
  margin-top:0 !important;
}" to remove the space at the top but it had no effect. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: The margin on top probably is attached to a parent element... But you can try a negative margin... Like `.fc-toolbar{ margin-top:-0.5em !important; }` where a "em" depends on your font-size... ;)